# How do i add LIGHTBOX to Attachments?

Tags: attachments

How do i add the light box function

> rel="lightbox"

to the code below

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->ID), 1 ) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'large' ); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

i think most lightbox plugins require the rel or class attribute to be on the link, so:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->ID), 1 ) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'large' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: it doesn't work tells us almost nothing by which we can help you.  do you have a lightbox script loaded?

Answer (score 0):

@helgatheviking's solution is the correct one. If it doesn't work, then something else is wrong (e.g. is the lightbox script properly enqueued, etc.)

Alternatively, you can use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-balupton-edition/.

Or one of the few others in the WordPress plugin repository: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/lightbox.